# Why does using npx create-react-app keep getting stuck?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, command-line, create-react-app, npx

Every time I try to create a react app it gets stuck. This is what I see

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                  npm update check failed                   │
│            Try running with sudo or get access             │
│            to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\alanp\.config │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\alanp\OneDrive\Desktop\Personal Projects\PictureDayAtl\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

It will just stay there. I checked my project out and it does end up creating a my-app folder and a package.json, but thats about it. I have I have up to date node and npm. Ive tried installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts before hand but that doesnt work. Ive tried repeating this multiple times and nothing. Left it run for a couple hours and nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could run with argument parameter ``--verbose`` to see what's happening

Comment: did you run this without Internet?

Comment: No, both of these still only get me to the part where it trys to install react, react-dom, and react-strips. After that they just get stuck again.